# How to fail silently when using Redisson for cache?

Tags: redisson

I'm using Redisson for caching. Are there any way to make the Redisson fail silently if my Redis instance is offline?

Since I'm using Redis just for caching it will be ok to just ignore some failures for while and just log it.

Comment: Which type of Redisson cache are you using?

Comment: I'm using RedissonSpringCacheManager